# Filter a List in Python With List Elements

Tags: python, filter

I have a following list

```
list = ['Bucket1', 'ranbuck0', 'ranbuck1', 'ranbuck2', 'ranbuck3', 'ranbuck4', 'ranbuck5', 'ranbuck6', 'ranbuck7', 'ranbuck8', 'ranbuck9']
```

Is there a way to filter this list and create a new list, where I have the  elements named with "ranbuck". I am not able to figure out the way how to iterate ranbuck1, ranbuck2 a append these in a list.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [list comprehension syntax of Python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
new_list = [_ for _ in list if 'ranbuck' in _]
```

Instead of the `_`s you could also introduce your own variable name for the temporary variable inside the list comprehension. Instead of `'ranbuck' in _` you could also write down another condition whether this element of the list should be in the new one or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension as suggested by mxscho or `filter`:

```
source_list = ['Bucket1', 'ranbuck0', 'ranbuck1', 'ranbuck2',
               'ranbuck3', 'ranbuck4', 'ranbuck5', 'ranbuck6',
               'ranbuck7', 'ranbuck8', 'ranbuck9']

filtered_list = filter(lambda item: 'ranbuck' in item, source_list)
```

I renamed your initial 'list' to source_list, as `list` is a python builtin